# Keyboard interrupts in long mode. 64 bit os

Tags: c, assembly, kernel, x86-64, interrupt

I try to create my first os from 0 using different tutorials. Now I have a simple kernel with simple paging, GDT for 64 bit, and entering to long mode. But there is a problem with keyboard interrupts. I read lots of topics about that and I think its a double-fault when start typing. Please, help me to understand and fix this problem. Here is repository with my code https://github.com/alexanderian76/TestOS
So, the problem is if I type anything, QEMU resets system instead showing symbols on display. Each interrupt resets it, as I understand.
This is my gdt64 and enter to long-mode

```
gdt64:
    dq 0 ; zero entry
.code: equ $ - gdt64 ; new
    dq (1<<43) | (1<<44) | (1<<47) | (1<<53) ; code segment
.pointer:
    dw $ - gdt64 - 1
    dq gdt64
```

This is enter to long mode.

```
start:
    mov esp, stack_top

    call check_multiboot
    call check_cpuid
    call check_long_mode

    call set_up_page_tables ; new
    call enable_paging     ; new

    ; print `OK` to screen
    mov dword [0xb8000], 0x2f4b2f4f
    
    lgdt [gdt64.pointer]
    jmp gdt64.code:long_mode_start
    
    hlt



long_mode_start:
    ; print `OKAY` to screen
    mov ax, 0
    mov ss, ax
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov fs, ax
    mov gs, ax

    
    mov rax, 0x2f592f412f4b2f4f
    mov qword [0xb8000], rax
    
   call main
   
    hlt
```

And this is IDT

```
#define PIC2_COMMAND 0xA0
#define PIC2_DATA 0xA1

#define ICW1_INIT 0x10
#define ICW1_ICW4 0x01
#define ICW4_8086 0x01



struct IDT_entry {
    unsigned short offset_lowerbits;
    unsigned short selector;
    unsigned char ist;
    unsigned short offset_mid;
    unsigned int zero;
    unsigned char type_attr;
    unsigned int offset_higherbits;
};
//*********************************


extern struct IDT_entry IDT[IDT_SIZE];

void load_idt_entry()
{
   for(unsigned long long int t = 0; t < 256; t++) {
    IDT[t].offset_lowerbits = (unsigned short)(((unsigned long long int)&isr1 & 0x000000000000ffff));
    IDT[t].offset_mid = (unsigned short)(((unsigned long long int)&isr1 & 0x00000000ffff0000) >> 16);
    IDT[t].offset_higherbits = (unsigned int)(((unsigned long long int)&isr1 & 0xffffffff00000000) >> 32);
    IDT[t].selector = 0x08;
    IDT[t].type_attr = 0x8e;
    IDT[t].zero = 0;
    IDT[t].ist = 0;
    
    

    RemapPic();

    outb(0x21, 0xfd);
    outb(0xa1, 0xff);
    
    
    LoadIDT();
   }
}

void outb(unsigned short port, unsigned char val){
  asm volatile ("outb %0, %1" : : "a"(val), "Nd"(port));
}

unsigned char inb(unsigned short port){
  unsigned char returnVal;
  asm volatile ("inb %1, %0"
  : "=a"(returnVal)
  : "Nd"(port));
  return returnVal;
}

void RemapPic(){
  unsigned char a1, a2;

  a1 = inb(PIC1_DATA);
  a2 = inb(PIC2_DATA);
  outb(PIC1_COMMAND, ICW1_INIT | ICW1_ICW4);
  outb(PIC2_COMMAND, ICW1_INIT | ICW1_ICW4);
  outb(PIC1_DATA, 0);
  outb(PIC2_DATA, 8);
  outb(PIC1_DATA, 4);
  outb(PIC2_DATA, 2);
  outb(PIC1_DATA, ICW4_8086);
  outb(PIC2_DATA, ICW4_8086);

  outb(PIC1_DATA, a1);
  outb(PIC2_DATA, a2);

}
```

Sorry, this the first time I ask something here, but I cant solve this problem by myself.
Thank you so much!

Comment: What did your debugger (VM) tell you? Do you have a double fault handler? What info does that provide?

Comment: Not related to your problem but you shouldn't be mapping the PICs ontop of the exception handler table. This code `outb(PIC1_DATA, 0);
  outb(PIC2_DATA, 8);` maps the pics to the first 16 interrupts ontop of the exceptions. Put them after the exceptions at 0x20 to 0x2f with something like ` outb(PIC1_DATA, 0x20);
  outb(PIC2_DATA, 0x28);`

Comment: I use gdb and readelf. No, I dont have a double fault handler

Comment: So, when I try typing, QEMU resets system, thats why I think its a double fault

Comment: QEMU or BOCHS should be able to tell you what faults happened leading up to a double or triple fault.  If you're not getting that info, *that's* the problem you should be trying to solve; with a good debugging setup, many more bugs become easy to find and solve, including simple typos, brain farts, and wrong values that aren't easy to see when looking at the source code.

Comment: I **strongly** recommend you get all your exception handlers working and tested before you move on to anything else. Debugging a kernel is difficult enough as it is.

Comment: You may find it useful to use qemu options '-d int -no-shutdiwn -no-reboot' . It will display the interrupt info when you hit a a key and and it faults. It is likely a general protection fault (0x0d) followed by a double fault. The GPF should show an error code and a register dump.  All that info could be useful for the question.

Comment: As sj95126 pointed out: make sure the IDT is valid first. Set it up and try an `int xx` instruction. BTW, did you put  `LoadIDT` and similar in the loop? It seems you have a `sti` in `LoadIDT`, while the IDT is being built. Also is the structure packed or is the compiler aligning the field after the char-sized ones?

Comment: Yeah the IDT seems broken. Bochs says _"interrupt(long mode): unsupported gate type 2"_ and _"IDT entry extended attributes DWORD4 TYPE != 0"_

Comment: Your `IDT_entry` seems to have the fields in the wrong order. `type_attr` should be after the `ist` and the `zero` should be at the end.

Comment: Also your `POPALL` macro actually has pushes not pops.

Comment: @Margaret Bloom: actually I wouldn't recommend testing the exception handlers with ```int xx``` because that won't push an error code on the stack. Handlers like ```#PF``` or ```#GP``` need to be tested by actually triggering a fault.

Comment: @sj95126 Yes, I agree, I implicitly assumed that the OP would know that. It's good you pointed that out :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `IDT_entry` seems to have the fields in the wrong order. `type_attr` should be after the `ist` and the `zero` should be at the end. Also your `POPALL` macro actually has pushes not pops.

```
diff --git a/long_mode_init.asm b/long_mode_init.asm
index cd64e24..926afae 100644
--- a/long_mode_init.asm
+++ b/long_mode_init.asm
@@ -19,13 +19,13 @@ extern IDT
 %endmacro
 
 %macro POPALL 0
-    push r11
-    push r10
-    push r9
-    push r8
-    push rdx
-    push rcx
-    push rax
+    pop r11
+    pop r10
+    pop r9
+    pop r8
+    pop rdx
+    pop rcx
+    pop rax
 %endmacro
     
 
diff --git a/main.c b/main.c
index b1bfa1c..22ef2fe 100644
--- a/main.c
+++ b/main.c
@@ -41,10 +41,10 @@ struct IDT_entry {
    unsigned short offset_lowerbits;
    unsigned short selector;
     unsigned char ist;
-    unsigned short offset_mid;
-   unsigned int zero;
    unsigned char type_attr;
+    unsigned short offset_mid;
    unsigned int offset_higherbits;
+   unsigned int zero;
 };
 //*********************************
```

With these changes it does no longer crash.

Comment: Thank you very much! It helped me. Maybe you can recommend any debugging tools to catch such mistakes?

Comment: @Alexander: I do most of my debugging with gdb connected to the QEMU session - see [here](https://wiki.osdev.org/Kernel_Debugging) for details. You can set a breakpoint at the first instruction of your exception handler and step through it. If you don't reach that point, the IDT entry has a problem.

Comment: @sj95126 : for this I'd use an x86-64 enabled version BOCHs. Mainly for 2 reasons. One is that BOCHs allows you to easily debug protected mode to real mode switch and switches from 16 to 32-bit and long mode. QEMU doesn't do well with that at all especially newer versions. Secondly BOCHs has very good commands to dump the IDT table and the GDT (as well as the GDTR and IDTR) and the page tables and it can tell you at a glance if those are munged.

Comment: @Michael Petch: I agree, Bochs is better for debugging issues before you reach protected mode, bu I find gdb easier after that point. Bochs also has a few warts, like not properly identifying a 64-bit TSS. But I do occasionally need one or the other, depending on the issue.

Comment: @sj95126 : Agreed. Those warts are minor compared to the slug that is QEMU for that kind of thing lol. There was a patch previously for the 64-bit TSS issue as well as the old problem of the virtual page mappings not appearing for addresses above 4GB etc.